# How to declare static property of a static type?

Tags: c#

I want to declare sort of a configuration class. I want to access the properties as `Config.Params1.Prop1`.
I get `cannot declare a variable of static type` when I use the code below.
I understand why I get the error, but how do I declare the classes to get what I want?

```
public static class Config
{
    public static Section1 Params1;
}

public static class Section1
{
    public static string Prop1 => "...";
    public static string Prop2 => "...";
}
```

Comment: I have a question, why?

Comment: It's a temproray solution before I refactor and move everything to config file

Comment: Use a `singleton` instance instead.

Comment: @theateist is this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do, it because Params1 is an object, not a class. But You can do this.

```
public static class Config
{
    public static Section1 Params1;
}

public class Section1
{
    public string Prop1 => "...";
    public  string Prop2 => "...";
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Config.Params1 = new Section1();
    var temp = Config.Params1.Prop1;
```

Or this, with your existing solution.

```
var temp = Section1.Prop1;
```

Or if you want to access like `Config.Section1.Prop1`  then you can simply do this.

```
namespace Config
{
    public static class Section1
    {
        public static string Prop1 => "...";
        public static string Prop2 => "...";
    }
```

You can also make the class `Params1` inside the `Config` class.

```
public static class Config
{
    public static class Params1
    {
        public static string Prop1 => "...";
        public static string Prop2 => "...";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your class nested:

```
public static class Config
{

    public static class Params1    
    {
        public static string Prop1 => "...";
        public static string Prop2 => "...";
    }
}
```

you need to rename Section1 to Params1 for full effect.